# Проблема с использованием блоков в Django

Tags: python, django, django-model

Vожете помочь? Есть файл home.html, в нем представлена стартовая страница. В файле home.html я заношу некоторые блоки кода для дальнейшего использования в других файлах. Но когда я использую занесенные блоки кода home.html в новом html-файле, то вся информация из прошлого файла дублируется.

Я хотел занести такие блоки кода из html: head и header. Я не понимаю почему другие элементы тоже скопировались, в чем проблема? можете помочь или просто скинуть ссылку на нужную доку?

home.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}">
  </head>
{% endblock %}
<body>
  {% block header %}
    <header class="header container-home">
      <div class="header-img">
        <div class="header-img-logo">
          <img src="{% static 'main/img/yaroslav.svg' %}" alt="logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  {% endblock %}
  <div class="container-home">
    <div class="container-home-text">
      <div class="container-home-text-title">
        Небольшое приложение на Django по авторизации и регистрации
      </div>
      <div class="container-home-text-subtitle-subtitle">
        Небольшое приложение созданное на фреимворке Django, для тренировки. 
        Суть этого небольшого приложения в том, что оно дает пользователю 
        возможность регистрации и авторизации на веб-странице
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-home-buttons">
      <div class="container-home-buttons-register">
        <a href="{% url 'register' %}">
          <button>Регистрация</button>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="container-home-buttons-autho">
        <a href="#">
          <button>Авторизация</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

register.html:

```
{% extends 'main/home.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: «почему другие элементы тоже скопировались» — потому что так именно работает extends, что буквально следует из его названия — вы расширяете шаблон, а не выдираете куски из него